# Upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04 on Dell machine and Dell repo no longer has a public key in update

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, dell, gnupg

I recently upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04 on a Dell Inspiron. When I ran apt-get update after the upgrade I got the following error:

```
Get:1 http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease [197 kB]
Err:1 http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease                                                                  
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D4D1EAED36962F69 NO_PUBKEY F9FDA6BED73CDC22
```

Other updating sources followed, then the following at the end:

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D4D1EAED36962F69 NO_PUBKEY F9FDA6BED73CDC22
W: Failed to fetch http://dell.archive.canonical.com/dists/jammy/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D4D1EAED36962F69 NO_PUBKEY F9FDA6BED73CDC22
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have tried manually adding the keys using GPG and the keys from this website:

https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-uk/dell-update-packages-v17.10.00/dup_17.10_users_guide/verifying-the-digital-signature-on-systems-running-linux?guid=guid-09dffd8a-0b1e-4db0-9ea4-6b1477793ba2&lang=en-us

However this did not work unfortunately. Is there any way to know if not being able to update from this repo affects anything? Or better yet is there a solution to this I have not considered yet?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: tried to find the key in https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/ ?